# How to upload multiple files in Alfresco using custom content type of Drupal using CMIS module?

Tags: entities

How to upload multiple files in Alfresco using custom content type of Drupal using [CMIS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis)?

In **settings.php**, i have configured like below,

```
$conf['cmis_sync_map'] = array(
   'alfresco_upload' => array(
   'enabled' => TRUE,
   'cmis_folderPath' => '/Sites/beneficiery/documentLibrary/first', // you need to create a site and add a custom foder in it (on Alfresco side)
  //'content_field' => 'field_upload1',

  /*array(
    'drupal' => 'some_other_custom_field',
    'cmis' => 'cmis:someOtherCustomProperty',
    'cmis to drupal' => TRUE,
    'drupal to cmis' => TRUE
    ),*/
  array(
    'title' => 'cmis:name'
    'field_upload1' => 'cmis:file',
    'field_upload2' => 'cmis:file'
    ),

 ),
'deletes' => TRUE,
);
```

How to give files in the array list to store files in alfresco ?

or if any other method available, please let me know,